# More efficient way to include empty rows than LEFT JOIN on same table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Consider the following table:

```
 ____________________________________
|          my_table                  |  
| ID | val_1 | val_2 | val_3 | val_4 |  
| 1  |   1   |   1   |   2   |   0   |
| 2  |   1   |   2   |   8   |   1   |
| 3  |   1   |   2   |   9   |   1   |  
| 4  |   1   |   2   |   10  |   1   |  
| 5  |   1   |   3   |   6   |   1   |  
| 6  |   1   |   4   |   8   |   1   |  
| 7  |   2   |   1   |   14  |   1   |  
| 8  |   2   |   2   |   1   |   0   |  
| 8  |   2   |   2   |   8   |   1   |  
| 8  |   2   |   3   |   2   |   0   |  
 ------------------------------------
```

I need `sum(val_3)` for every combination of `val_1,val_2` where `val_4=1`, or `0` if there is no `val_4=1` for the given `val_1,val_2`

This query gets the proper sum grouping, but does not include a `0` value for empty combinations:

```
select val_1,val_2,sum(val_3) from my_table where val_4 = 1 group by val_1,val_2
```

I can get the proper result with a combination of `LEFT JOIN` on the same table and `IFNULL(<condition>,0)`

The first query averages .22 seconds on my dataset.  The `LEFT JOIN` / `IFNULL` query averages 0.98 seconds.  Is there a query structure that will include the `0` values and perform closer to the 0.22s time of the first query?  My script may run this query a few thousand times per call.

This is actually a subquery to an outer query that calculates the `stdev_samp()` of `val_3`, so I do need to include 0 values.

Comment: I ran your query which gives "proper result". For `val_1,val_2` combination of `2,2`, it is returning 16 as the sum. However, I think it should be 8 only. Please confirm. Check the fiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hBSNK9s7LmacfLSV2BwhXg/0

Comment: @Madhur My mistake.  It had been a long day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do conditional aggregation without using any Derived Tables (subquery), or `Left Join`.

**Query**

```
SELECT
  val_1,
  val_2, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN val_4 = 1 THEN val_3
           ELSE 0 
      END) AS sum 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY val_1, val_2;
```

**Result**

```
| val_1 | val_2 | sum |
| ----- | ----- | --- |
| 1     | 1     | 0   |
| 1     | 2     | 27  |
| 1     | 3     | 6   |
| 1     | 4     | 8   |
| 2     | 1     | 14  |
| 2     | 2     | 8   |
| 2     | 3     | 0   |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hBSNK9s7LmacfLSV2BwhXg/1)

Comment: Works well.  I get an average query time ~.31s.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without your obvious data to test and compare to, I offer the following.  The inner query goes through the list ONCE and does a sum as both the val_4 = 1 AND when = 0 as respective individual column results with the grouping.  Once this is done, all combinations are already resolved with the group by.  So now the outer query gets the Val 1 & 2, but a case-when for the final.  If there is a value in the SumWhen1 > 0, we know there WAS a value with a 1.  If no value, then it returns the sumWhen0 results.

```
SELECT
      pq.Val_1,
      pq.Val_2,
      CASE when PQ.SumWhen1 > 0 then SumWhen1 else SumWhen0 end FinalSum
   from
      ( select 
              val_1,
              val_2,
              sum( CASE when val_4 = 1 then val_2 else 0 end ) SumWhen1,
              sum( CASE when val_4 = 0 then val_2 else 0 end ) SumWhen0,
           from 
              my_table 
           where 
              val_4 = 1 
           group by 
              val_1,
              val_2 ) PQ
```

Now, if your data can contain negatives, I would just add to the inner query the following and use this column as the basis to confirm a val_4 had any records.

```
          sum( CASE when val_4 = 1 then 1 else 0 end ) Val1Records,
```

Comment: The actual data set (and aggregate calculation in the query) is very complex.  I don't think it's practical to try to post even a subset of it.  I'll give this a try and advise.

Comment: @matt, I completely understand, but obviously could not run and give any comparable time, just a POSSIBLE option to help :)